# Call method on object literal

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a method on an object that was just created using object literal notation?
I tried this:

```
{myMethod:function(arg){console.log(arg);}}.myMethod(0);
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Why does it not work? Can I only do this by assigning the object to some variable and call its method via the variable?

Answer (score 4):

Simply wrap the object in parenthesis.

```js
({myMethod:function(arg){console.log(arg);}}).myMethod(0);
```